# Beamer: How to reveal one section at a time in TOC in column environment

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have put my table of contents into two column environments for top alignment and more control over column breaks. The problem is, the pausesections and pausesubsections displays consecutive line of both columns simultaneously. I want to show the consecutive rows of the first column, then consecutive rows of the second column. I tried using overlay specifications without success.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} % 16:9 aspect ratio
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Font encoding
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}  % Allows multirows in equations and multicolumns in slides

% Uncover everything in step-wise fashion
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Overview}
    \begin{columns}<*>[t]
        \begin{column}<+->{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-2},pausesections,pausesubsections]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}<+->{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={3-},pausesections,pausesubsections]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 5}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: Here is my results]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} % 16:9 aspect ratio
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Font encoding
\usepackage{multirow}  % Allows multirows in equations and multicolumns in slides

% Uncover everything in step-wise fashion
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\trickbeamer}[1]{%
    \advance\beamer@slideinframe by #1 %
}%

\newcommand{\slideinframe}{\the\beamer@slideinframe}
\newcounter{foo}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Overview}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-2},pausesections,pausesubsections]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \only<.>{\setcounter{foo}{\slideinframe}}
            \trickbeamer{-\thefoo}\tableofcontents[sections={3-},pausesections,pausesubsections]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Section 5}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}


\end{document}
```